# Java regex replace values

Tags: java, regex, replace

I am trying to replace certain values from a string using java regex

for example the string looks like

```
:20:1234
    6789
:28G::xyz
|20:3456
    1234
|29C:pqr
:20|9876
```

I want to replace tag 20 value (may be multi line value) for second occurrence

```
|20:3456
    1234
```

with new value(may be multi line value) 6789 so the final replacement string i am expecting is

```
:20:1234
    6789
:28G::xyz
|20:6789
|29C:pqr
:20|9876
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but it seems that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22586702/2736496) to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586639/java-regex-to-create-map-from-multi-line-string) about a half-hour ago, contains concepts that will also help you here.

Comment: Why does the `|29C:pqr` change to `::29C:pqr`?

Comment: It was typo corrected it now, thxs

Answer (score 0):

This should work (tested):

```
str.replaceAll("(\\|" + "20" + ":)[^|:]*\n","$1" + "6789" + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
String str = ":20:1234\n    6789\n:28G::xyz\n|20:3456\n    1234\n|29C:pqr\n:20|9876 \n|20:3456\n    :20:1234\n";
str = str.replaceAll("(\\|20:)[\\s\\S]*?(?=[|:])","$1" + "6789\n");
```

Here it is checking until it reaches to anything other than `|` or `:`, so that it doesn't pick all.